# Short dynamic link not generated in react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am not able to generate short dynamic link for sharing. We are using firebase dynamic link share.At the time of link generation got following error

> [dynamicLinks/build-failed] The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link: XXXX [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]

Here is my code

```
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

export async function buildDynamicLink(Id) {


    try {

        let shortLink = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
            link: 'https://www.xyx.com?id=' + (Id),
            domainUriPrefix: 'https://xyz.page.link',
            social:{
                title: 'xxx',
                descriptionText: 'xxx'
            },
            ios:{
                bundleId : 'com.xxx.application'
            },
            android: {
                packageName: 'com.xxx.application'
            }
        },"SHORT")
        return shortLink
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tested your code in our app where we use dynamiclinks 7.5.13 and it worked perfectly fine.

How long is the link you are trying to shorten? Maybe try with a different link length to exclude that as the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have no issue with link build up but I need privacy protection for link identification so I need short url. url is very short not added any parameter

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "i have no issue with link build up"? As I told you your code works and I was able to generate links in the form of "domain.com/abd"

Comment: if we build normal link then parameter shown in encode formate and anyone can decode that so need short link

Comment: The short link is no way a security protection. The short link is a redirection to the long link. So when I click your short link I'm redirected to the real link and I will be able to read your URL params.

Comment: No issue where it's take but when i post the link on social media then long link will no longer visible to user

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Your original post is about "unable to generate short link". Now you are saying that you can generate it, but the long link will not be visible? So what exactly is the problem? Please reformulate your original question.

Comment: @deniel I am able to build the long link with `buildLink` but in that link i have passed some information for called api when user click on that link and that parameter clearly visible to anyone on shared platform so i want to generate short link so my param like package name or ios bundle identifier information no longer visible